# Can not start PostgreSQL replication resource with Corosync/Pacemaker

Tags: postgresql, cluster, replication, pacemaker, corosync

I'm setting up a PostgreSQL replication on two servers (CentOS 6.5) with HA by Corosync/Pacemaker.

My software info:

```
postgresql91-9.1.19-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
postgresql91-server-9.1.19-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
postgresql91-libs-9.1.19-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
postgresql91-contrib-9.1.19-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
postgresql91-devel-9.1.19-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64


corosynclib-1.4.7-2.el6.x86_64
corosync-1.4.7-2.el6.x86_64

pacemaker-cli-1.1.12-8.el6_7.2.x86_64
pacemaker-1.1.12-8.el6_7.2.x86_64
pacemaker-cluster-libs-1.1.12-8.el6_7.2.x86_64
pacemaker-libs-1.1.12-8.el6_7.2.x86_64

resource-agents-3.9.5-24.el6_7.1.x86_64
```

The replication is working, from master I can see the slave server connected:

`-bash-4.1$ psql -c "select client_addr,sync_state from pg_stat_replication;"
 client_addr | sync_state 
-------------+------------
 172.16.1.10 | async
(1 row)`

And I also confirm that data created on master is replicated to slave.

Here is my `crm configure show`:

```
node master                                                                  
node slave

primitive PSQL pgsql \
    params restart_on_promote=true pgctl="/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_ctl" psql="/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql" pgdata="/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data" node_list="master slave" repuser=rep rep_mode=sync restore_command="cp /var/lib/pgsql/pg_archive/%f %p" primary_conninfo_opt="keepalives_idle=60 keepalives_interval=5 keepalives_count=5" master_ip=172.16.1.100 archive_cleanup_command="/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/pgsql/pg_archive/ %r"
primitive RepIP IPaddr2 \
    params ip=172.16.1.100 nic=eth2 cidr_netmask=24 \
    op monitor interval=30s
primitive VirtualIP IPaddr2 \
    params ip=10.0.0.100 cidr_netmask=24 \
    op monitor interval=30s
group psql-ha VirtualIP RepIP \
    meta target-role=Started
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
    dc-version=1.1.11-97629de \
    cluster-infrastructure="classic openais (with plugin)" \
    expected-quorum-votes=2 \
    stonith-enabled=false \
    no-quorum-policy=ignore
```

But the resource `PSQL` can not start. My `crm status`:

```
Last updated: Sat Nov 28 13:09:47 2015
Last change: Sat Nov 28 12:50:21 2015
Stack: classic openais (with plugin)
Current DC: master - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.11-97629de
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
3 Resources configured


Online: [ master slave ]

 Resource Group: psql-ha
     VirtualIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started master 
     RepIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started master 

Failed actions:
    PSQL_start_0 on slave 'not configured' (6): call=60, status=complete, last-rc-change='Sat Nov 28 12:50:21 2015', queued=0ms, exec=53ms
```

There is an error log in `/var/log/messages`:

> Nov 28 12:50:21 slave pgsql(PSQL)[3387]: ERROR: Replication(rep_mode=async or sync) requires Master/Slave configuration.

Could anyone explain for me why I got that error?

Thanks.

UPDATED:

(name of hosts changed to node1/node2)

Problem solved with configuration of @gf_.

**Note: Forget about my old configuration, I'm using only one virtual IP in this deployment model.**

Current status:

```
[root@node1 ~]# crm_mon -Af -1
Last updated: Wed Dec  2 05:13:56 2015
Last change: Wed Dec  2 05:10:06 2015
Stack: classic openais (with plugin)
Current DC: node2 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.11-97629de
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
3 Resources configured


Online: [ node1 node2 ]

 VirtualIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node2 
 Master/Slave Set: msPSQL [PSQL]
     Masters: [ node2 ]
     Slaves: [ node1 ]

Node Attributes:
* Node node1:
    + PSQL-data-status                  : STREAMING|SYNC
    + PSQL-status                       : HS:sync   
    + master-PSQL                       : 100       
* Node node2:
    + PSQL-data-status                  : LATEST    
    + PSQL-master-baseline              : 000000000E000078
    + PSQL-status                       : PRI       
    + master-PSQL                       : 1000      

Migration summary:
* Node node1: 
* Node node2:
```

Working configuration:

```
node node1 \
    attributes PSQL-data-status="STREAMING|SYNC"
node node2 \
    attributes PSQL-data-status=LATEST
primitive PSQL pgsql \
    params restart_on_promote=false pgctl="/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_ctl" psql="/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql" pgdata="/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data" node_list="node1 node2" repuser=replicate rep_mode=sync restore_command="cp /var/lib/pgsql/pg_archive/%f %p" primary_conninfo_opt="keepalives_idle=60 keepalives_interval=5 keepalives_count=5" master_ip=10.0.0.100 archive_cleanup_command="/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/pgsql/pg_archive/ %r" \
    op start timeout=60s interval=0s on-fail=restart \
    op monitor timeout=60s interval=4s on-fail=restart \
    op monitor timeout=60s interval=3s on-fail=restart role=Master \
    op promote timeout=60s interval=0s on-fail=restart \
    op demote timeout=60s interval=0s on-fail=stop \
    op stop timeout=60s interval=0s on-fail=block \
    op notify timeout=60s interval=0s
primitive VirtualIP IPaddr2 \
    params ip=10.0.0.100 nic=eth1 cidr_netmask=24 \
    op monitor interval=30s
ms msPSQL PSQL \
    meta master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1 target-role=Started notify=true
colocation rsc_colocation-1 inf: VirtualIP msPSQL:Master
order rsc_order-1 0: msPSQL:promote VirtualIP:start symmetrical=false
order rsc_order-2 0: msPSQL:promote VirtualIP:stop symmetrical=false
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
    dc-version=1.1.11-97629de \
    cluster-infrastructure="classic openais (with plugin)" \
    expected-quorum-votes=2 \
    no-quorum-policy=ignore \
    stonith-enabled=false \
    last-lrm-refresh=1449033003
rsc_defaults rsc-options: \
    resource-stickiness=100
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Another hint: Remember to set up [fencing](http://clusterlabs.org/wiki/FAQ#Do_I_need_a_fencing_device.3F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- At the same time, `PSQL` should run on both of your nodes, `master` and `slave`. (Just a small note: Not sure if these terms are good to choose as node names in your setup.)
- So, you have to reflect this in your configuration, the error you've got is quite clear, and describes, what's missing: You've to configure your `PSQL` as a cloned (should run on multiple nodes, at the same time), multi-state (should run in a master-slave-setup) resource. If you've got no idea, what this is about, now would be a good time to have a look into the docs, especially for [Clones - Resources That Get Active on Multiple Hosts](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-resource-clone.html) and [Multi-state - Resources That Have Multiple Modes](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-resource-multistate.html).
- So, your extended configuration could look like this:

  ```
  ms msPSQL PSQL \
  meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" clone-max="2" clone-node-max="1" notify="true"
  ```
- Additionally, you have to specify, on which of your nodes your `VirtualIP` and `RepIP` [should run](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-resource-sets-colocation.html), and you have to make sure, that the resources are stopped / started in [correct order](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-resource-ordering.html):

  ```
  colocation rsc_colocation-1 inf: psql-ha msPSQL:Master
  order rsc_order-1 0: msPSQL:promote psql-ha:start symmetrical=false
  order rsc_order-2 0: msPSQL:demote psql-ha:stop symmetrical=false
  ```

Comment: Thank you @gf_ it works now. I got some troubles with replication and also had to deal with cleanup resource (`crm_resource --cleanup --resource msPSQL`). Your configuration is totally correct (: I also updated my configuration and current status in question.